# Dynamically add fields in a Flutter Form Widget

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, dart

I've been looking for answers for a whole day, I'm tryin to add fields in a form dynamically (for the moment, by creating a loop which create fields), I can't find any answer for my problem. If you can do something, just let me know :

I'm creating a view with my Fieldset class, which is my form and I put a Field list inside :

```
List<Field> fieldset;

void main() {

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  Field field = Field();
  fieldset.add(field);
};
runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final appTitle = 'Form Validation Demo';

return MaterialApp(
  title: appTitle,
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text(appTitle),
    ),
    body: Fieldset(fieldset: List<Field>()),
  ),
);
}
}
```

As you can see, I'm just launching the app, creating some fields with the loop and putting it in Fieldset Widget go ahead :

```
class Fieldset extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Field> fieldset;
final state = _FieldsetState();

@override
_ FieldsetState createState() {
return _FieldsetState();
}

Fieldset({this.fieldset});


}

class _FieldsetState extends State<Fieldset> {
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Form(
    key: _formKey,
    child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget> [
       // widget.fieldset.forEach((f) => f.build(context)) ==> THIS DOESN'T WORK
          ,
          RaisedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                Scaffold.of(context)
                    .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content:                                             Text('processing')));
              }
            },
            child: Text('Submit'),
          )
        ]));
}
}
```

I really hope you can help me, Looks like i've missed something..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var listOfFields = <Widget>[];
listOfFields.add(RaisedButton( onPressed : (){
  addNewField(); 
}, child: Text("Add new Field")
));
void addNewField(){
   setState((){
   listOfFields.add(TextFormField());
   });
}
final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>()

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key : _formKey,
      child :Scaffold(
       body : ListView.builder(
          itemCount: listOfFields.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
            return listOfFields[index]; 
          }
       )
    )
    );

  }
```

Comment: I understand this approch, but unfortunatly I can't call listOfFields.add inside _FieldsetState directly. But thanks for the trick, I'm on a good way ;)

Comment: Try widget.listOfFields to access listOfFields inside the _FieldsetState class